# Recruit more staff Peace Walker

Tags: metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

My current limit is **350** staff members. There is no more space for my soldiers in Mother Base so I have to fire weak employees or send them in conflict zones when the stronger ones are coming.

Is there any way to recruit more people and how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know 350 is the absolut limit for soldiers in Mother Base.

> Up to 350 soldiers can be recruited; excess staff caught in a mission
>   must be discharged and up to 50 vehicles can be captured over the
>   course of the game.

Hope I helped!